# Form builder: how to prevent duplicate contacts

Tags: duplicate-contacts, formbuilder

With Form Builder, do you know how I can prevent duplicate contacts creation with the same name and email?
I have not found anywhere how to set the 'dedupe rule' for the contact.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that it has probably already been developed and will be available in the next versions (perhaps 5.56 or 5.57). See [this PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24552)